# Turn off screen when laptop lid is closed

Tags: systemd, power-management

My laptop does not turn off the screen when the lid is closed. This is already present when booted from the Arch install stick.

The event itself is properly recognized since the system logs:

```
systemd-logind[500]: Lid opened.
systemd-logind[500]: Lid closed.
```

How can I tell the system I want the screen to be off when the lid is closed?

Comment: What dm are you using?

Comment: @Cyclic3: I directly boot into [i3](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/i3).

Comment: `man logind.conf`

Comment: @Suuuehgi I have never used i3 before. Stupid question: have you looked around for a 'turn off the screen when not in use'

Comment: @jasonwryan: Could you tell me what I am supposed to find/search for there?

Comment: @jasonwryan Tell me if I'm wrong, but won't that only configure system actions such as locking the computer and putting it to sleep? I believe the OP wants to only turn off the screen.

Comment: @Cyclic3: I don't understand, what you mean by *turn off the screen when not in use*. Interestingly the screen turns off after x seconds of inactivity but not when the lid is closed.

Answer (score 4):

I now found an answer that works for me (single user system).

Although `systemd-logind` handles [ACPI events](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ACPI_modules), there is just a standard set of options `poweroff`, `reboot`, `halt`, ... (see `man logind.conf`) that don't include the screen alone.

The predecessor [`acpid`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/acpid) also provides handlers to act on ACPI events such as lid close. The simplest way is to directly <s>clutter</s> use the demo file `/etc/acpi/handler.sh` and alter the section

```
button/lid)
    case "$3" in
        close)
            logger 'LID closed'
            ;;
        open)
            logger 'LID opened'
            ;;
        *)
            logger "ACPI action undefined: $3"
            ;;
```

to

```
button/lid)
    case "$3" in
        close)
            logger 'LID closed'
            XAUTHORITY=/home/USERNAME/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force off
            ;;
        open)
            logger 'LID opened'
            XAUTHORITY=/home/USERNAME/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force on
            ;;
        *)
            logger "ACPI action undefined: $3"
            ;;
```

(For extensive use of `acpid` it is certainly adviced to create a separate rule/file for this task.)

## Explanation

`xset dpms force off` implicitly turns off the screen `$DISPLAY` (otherwise `xset -d $DISPLAY dpms force off`). To do that it needs the cookie (authorization file) of the person that started `X` located at `$XAUTHORITY`.

In case `X` was started by `root` during the login process (what is the standard case), a simgple `xset dpms force off` might be sufficient.

I start `X` within the `~/.shellrc` config of my login shell. I hence have to manually give it the display and cookie of me.

---

## Addendum

One can <s>fiddle</s> tweak that even further to not use the command when on AC (`xset` turns off *all* attached screens and `udev` does not detect the lid switch on my system).

```
        close)
            logger 'LID closed'
            if [[ $(cat /sys/class/power_supply/AC/online) == 0 ]];then
                XAUTHORITY=/home/USERNAME/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force off
            fi
            ;;
```

Comment: Is there a counterpart of `xset` for the linux console, i.e. when there is no X server running?